# How do I set the enter button to behave as return button in Xcode?

Tags: python, sikuli

I created a script to search on a data however there is no search button on the app. Just A text box. Is there any way on how to set the enter button to act as return button?

This is my code:

```
click(image)  
type("text")  
type(chr(13))
```

the ascii 13 is still equivalent to enter

Is it possible to code or set `enter = return button`? If yes how? Maybe you can help me out because I am a beginner in Python

Comment: Have you tried running this?

Comment: Yes i have tried the code that i've mentioned. However, it is pressing enter. I need a way to click/press on the return button. I am running my script on XCODE and one requirement is that the keyboard should  always be turned off.

Comment: So you would like to press [Enter] yourself, and the script would do a return?

Answer (score 0):

1. Hit ENTER button:

   `type(Key.ENTER)`
2. Click on the desired button:

   `click(yourButton.png)`